# XenServer 5.6.0 / XenCenter not allowing SR to Windows 7 share on Domain Controller for ISO's

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, network-share, xenserver, cifs

I'm unable to get an SR made using command prompt or using XenCenter's interface dialogs.

Here is the command I'm issuing:

```
xe-mount-iso-sr //<mycomputer.domain.controller>/iso_share -o username=<my_domain_username>,password=<my_domain_password,domainname=ucads,sec=ntlmv2
```

Here is the response from the command:

```
 =======================
 CIFS VFS: No response for cmd 114 mid 45629
 Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
 CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
 CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
 INFO: task cdrommon:6932 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

Also, I tried to do a SMB:///iso_share with same credentials on my MacBook and it connected just fine... :-\

Answer (score 0):

I am serving an iso directory on windows 7 to my XenServer 5.5 install just fine. I suggest you try to create the SR from the XenCenter gui